# Data not being displayed from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

am trying to make a small website for my assignment and am stuck in a page. Actually, my code is not working as nothing is being displayed and no error also is being displayed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

```
<?php
include ("masterzone/php/mysqli.php");

if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT tbl_name FROM listing_title where listing_title_ID=?")) {
    $tpe = $_GET['type'];
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $tpe);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($tbl_name);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT Name,Address,Phone,Email,Location,Time,Website,Photo1,Date_Published,Rating FROM $tbl_name where categories_ID=?")) {
        $cat1 = $_GET['cat'];
        $stmt1->bind_param("i", $cat1);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt1->bind_result($Name, $Address, $Phone, $Email, $Location, $Time, $Website, $Photo1, $Date_Published, $Rating);
        $stmt1->fetch();
        ?>
        <div id="loop_listing_taxonomy" class="list" >
            <div class="post listing-11323 ">
                <img src="images/<?php echo $Photo1; ?>"  alt="" title="" />
                <div class="entry">
                    <!--start post type title -->
                    <div class="listing-title">
                        <h2 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><?php echo $Name; ?></h2>
                        <div class="listing_rating">
                            <div class="directory_rating_row"><span class="single_rating">
                            <?php
                                for ($x = 1; $x <= $Rating; $x++) {
                                    echo '<img src="images/rating-on.png" alt="" />';
                                }
                            ?>
                            </span></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="phone"><?php echo $Phone; ?></p><p class="address"><?php echo $Address; echo $Location; ?></p><p class="time"><?php echo $Time; ?></p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $stmt1->close();
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. Start by checking your error logs...

Comment: Check your connexion and Mysql error logs or Apache...

Comment: add echo 'workin' before your include, change include to require_once, create a temp value and store the results of your query, and var_dump it. Basically, try to isolate the command that's causing the issue

Comment: no errors found on error logs.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest mysqli prepare statements...  and I think you meant to have a while statement for the second query...

Try something like this:

```
<?php
include ("masterzone/php/mysqli.php");

if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT tbl_name FROM listing_title where listing_title_ID=?")) {
    $tpe = $_GET['type'];
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $tpe);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($tbl_name);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if ($stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT Name,Address,Phone,Email,Location,Time,Website,Photo1,Date_Published,Rating FROM $tbl_name where categories_ID=?")) {
        $cat1 = $_GET['cat'];
        $stmt1->bind_param("i", $cat1);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt1->bind_result($Name, $Address, $Phone, $Email, $Location, $Time, $Website, $Photo1, $Date_Published, $Rating);
        while($stmt1->fetch()){
            ?>
            <div id="loop_listing_taxonomy" class="list" >
                <div class="post listing-11323 ">
                    <img src="images/<?php echo $Photo1; ?>"  alt="" title="" />
                    <div class="entry">
                        <!--start post type title -->
                        <div class="listing-title">
                            <h2 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><?php echo $Name; ?></h2>
                            <div class="listing_rating">
                                <div class="directory_rating_row"><span class="single_rating">
                                <?php
                                    for ($x = 1; $x <= $Rating; $x++) {
                                        echo '<img src="images/rating-on.png" alt="" />';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </span></div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="phone"><?php echo $Phone; ?></p><p class="address"><?php echo $Address; echo $Location; ?></p><p class="time"><?php echo $Time; ?></p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        $stmt1->free_result();
        $stmt1->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It works but the problem is that it not not retrieving all the data, It is retrieving only one data. Can't we use a loop (e.g: while loop) for prepared statements?